# Getting error in my code for a shipping calculator in Python

Tags: python

Thanks to everyone for the help. I got it working. Sorry if I asked a dumb question. Seems I had too many spaces in some places and then my enter_more command was just continuing to loop but I got it thanks again.

```
print("Shipping Calculator \n")


enter_more="y"

while enter_more.lower()=="y":

   itemcost=float(input("Cost of items ordered:"))
   if itemcost < 0:
       print("You must enter a positive number. Please try again.")
       continue 

   if itemcost >75:

    Shipping_cost=0

   elif itemcost >50:

    Shipping_cost=9.95



   elif itemcost >30:

    Shipping_cost=7.95


   else: 

    Shipping_cost =5.95

   print("Shipping cost:",Shipping_cost)

   total_cost =round(Shipping_cost + itemcost,2)

   print ("Total cost:",round(Shipping_cost + itemcost,2))

   print()

   enter_more = input("Continuie? y/n:")

   if enter_more.lower()!= "y":

         break


print("Bye!")
```

Comment: add one space character before print function in your original file

Comment: Your indentation is wrong on elif & else... those conditions should be offset the same as the original if condition.

Comment: I am not a pyhon programmer bu the if and elsif and else must have the same indent, this is not the case here nor in the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement should be indented correctly.

```
print("Shipping Calculator")
print()
itemcost=float(input("Cost of items ordered:"))
if itemcost <30.00:
     Shipping_cost=5.95
 elif itemcost >30.00 and <=49.99:
     Shipping_cost=7.95
 elif itemcost >50.00 and <=74.99:
     Shipping_cost=9.95
 else: 
     print("Shipping cost is FREE") 

print("Shipping cost:" + str (itemcost) + format(Shipping_cost))
```

This is because python's *code tree* (if you will, but I mean loops and if statements) don't have curly braces like the majority of programming languages. Instead, it looks at how the code is indented. With the way you wrote it, the compiler interprets the `elif` statements and the `else` statement as a separate if statement, and it's getting confused because there's no `if` statement. That's why you need to indent it correctly.

I guess that's python's way of forcing programmers to indent properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like this:

```
print("Shipping Calculator \n")
itemcost=float(input("Cost of items ordered:"))
if itemcost <30.00:
    Shipping_cost=5.95
elif itemcost >30.00 and itemcost <= 49.99:
    Shipping_cost=7.95
elif itemcost >50.00 and itemcost <=74.99:
    Shipping_cost=9.95
else: 
    print("Shipping cost is FREE") 

print("Shipping cost:" + str (itemcost) + Shipping_cost)
```

The reason you were getting the error is because you `elif` statement was inside of the `if`.

---

**Other points too note:**

- It's also a better practice to replace `print()` with `\n`
- the `format(Shipping_cost)` can be replaced with `Shipping_cost`
- If you want to use `format()` then you should change `print("Shipping cost:" + str (itemcost) + Shipping_cost)` with `print("Shipping cost:{}{}".format(str(itemcost),Shipping_cost))`

Comment: remove one space before `print` in `else` :)